# Two routers in an office space?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wired-networking

My company is moving into a new office building.

The space is pretty big, so I'm thinking of creating a wired network in case wi-fi is too slow and unreliable.

Can I have my ISP bring two lines from the building's main data-hub into the office space? I'm not sure how this would go, maybe two routers, one at each end of the office? I was thinking there might be too much traffic using only one router? Also not sure if the office equipment, i.e. printers, etc. can communicate properly if there are two routers. There will be about >15 staff.

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/set-up-your-small-business-network https://www.neweggbusiness.com/smartbuyer/over-easy/small-office-network-setup/

Answer (score 0):

20 or so staff can work off one router without much issue.

Key points:

1. Very fast, high throughput commercial router.
2. One fast switch at each end of the office works, but may not be necessary.
3. Make sure the ISP supplies enough bandwidth for all the staff activities. This is where the expense is (monthly cost for high bandwidth).
4. Make sure you have properly (commercially) installed Cat 6e wiring or Cat 7 wiring.
5. I assume 20 people are not more than 100 meters (300 feet) from the main network, but you will need a fast backbone and fast switch at the other end if that spread out.

It really is not very many people. We have done this with one router and one ISP point for several clients and it has worked well over the years.

You will want a separate ISP point, and separate wiring for top notch VOIP.  Do not combine this over your data network.

Comment: Sounds good. So I should just have one router. I'm trying to make the network somewhat hybrid, with both wired and wireless capabilities. There will be a couple computers that are mostly stationary and should connect to a printer. There will be another couple of computers connected to another printer. Then there will be some laptops that the staff will walk around with and ideally could connect to any of the printers. So I'm assuming all the printers and stationary computers should be connected together through switches and the one router?

Comment: One main, top quality and fast router will be fine even including printers. You can add wireless access point. For walk around simplicity locate a top quality wireless router to serve most thing and add a Ubiquiti Lite AP to serve another area. This will use the same SSID and you can have more than one.  Depends on your needs and layout.